# Can Timestamp for a signal be extracted from an mdf file in Python?

Tags: python, asammdf

I'm working with a large CAN log and have access to a .mf4 file only.
I was wondering whether you can get the timestamp at which a certain signal was sent, much like loading a .log file. I have only encountered `mdf.to_dataframe()` command whcih requires a raster and completely destroys the sampling time. I need to look at the time it takes for a device on my CAN line to spit consecutive messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from asammdf import MDF

with MDF('can_logging.mf4') as mdf:
    messages = mdf.get('CAN_DataFrame')
    print(messages.timestamps)
```

Comment: Thanks @danielhrisca. I am unable to use `mdf.get('CAN_DataFrame')` as well. I am getting the following error: 
`AttributeError: 'MDF4' object has no attribute '_raise_on_mutiple_occurences'`

I am able to access individual signals though. Not the entire mdf dataframe.

Comment: Install the latest development branch code or install versi0on 6.1.2

Comment: To get the absolute time, you can add it to `mdf.start_time`.

Comment: Again, regarding absolute time: Conversion might be a bit complicated due to accuracy problems. I solved it by using: `mdf.start_time + np.round(messages.timestamps * 1000, 0) * pd.offsets.Milli()` with `import pandas as pd` and `import numpy as np`. There probably is a more efficient way to it, but it works.